# How do I detect when '--help' has been called?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

My Click 7.0 application has one group, having multiple commands, called by the main `cli` function like so:

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
   "This is cli helptext"

    click.echo('cli called')
    click.echo('cli args: {0}'.format(ctx.args))

@cli.group(chain=True)
@click.option('-r', '--repeat', default=1, type=click.INT, help='repeat helptext')
@click.pass_context
def chainedgroup(ctx, repeat):
    "This is chainedgroup helptext"

    for _ in range(repeat):
        click.echo('chainedgroup called')
    click.echo('chainedgroup args: {0}'.format(ctx.args))

@chainedgroup.command()
@click.pass_context
def command1(ctx):
    "This is command1 helptext"

    print('command1 called')
    print('command1 args: {0}'.format(ctx.args))

@chainedgroup.command()
@click.pass_context
def command2(ctx):
    "This is command2 helptext"

    print('command2 called')
    print('command2 args: {0}'.format(ctx.args))
```

Run:

```
$ testcli --help
$ testcli chainedgroup --help
$ testcli chainedgroup command1 --help
```

The help-text displays as expected--except that the parent functions are inadvertently run in the process. A single conditional checking to see if `'--help'` is contained in `ctx.args` should be enough to solve this problem, but does anyone know how/when `'--help'` is passed? Because with this code, `ctx.args` is empty every time.

Comment: I should also note that I intend to use the `repeat` loop to [invoke](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/?highlight=types#click.BaseCommand.invoke) the passed commands over-and-over, but I can ask a separate question about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If argparse is not an option, how about:

```
if '--help' in sys.argv:
...
```

Comment: Disabling [`no_args_is_help`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.MultiCommand) and handling help manually via `sys.argv` solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

`click` stores the arguments passed to a command in a list. The method `get_os_args()` returns such list. You can check if `--help` is in that list to determine if the `help` flag was invoked. Something like the following:

```py
if '--help' in click.get_os_args():
    pass
```

Answer (score -3):

It is prebuilt - Click looks like a decorator for argparse (Hurrah for common sense).

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

So you can write

```
python cl.py --name bob
```

And see

Hello bob!

Help is already done (as it is argparse)

```
python cl.py --help
Usage: cl.py [OPTIONS]

  Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times.

Options:
  --count INTEGER  Number of greetings.
  --name TEXT      The person to greet.
  --help           Show this message and exit.
```

Been busy only just had time to read into this.

Sorry for the delay